# SQL Server OPENROWSET Msg 7302 Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"

Tags: sql-server, oledb, openrowset, excel-import

I am trying to create a procedure that import an excel sheet in my SQL Server database with SSMS (I am admin).

I have no problem when I do the import manually; my excel file is closed and I can modify it.

When I run this query :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.[Disp$] (Disp, Betrieb)
        SELECT Disp, betrieb
        FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'EXCEL 12.0;Database=Downloads\MyExcelFile.xlsx', 'SELECT * FROM [Disp$]');
END;
```

I get this message :

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Procedure test, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Here is what I have tried :

1. ```sql
   EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', N'AllowInProcess', 1
   ```
2. ```sql
   EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
   RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
   GO
   EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
   RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
   GO
   EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
   GO
   RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
   GO
   ```
3. ```sql
   EXEC master.sys.sp_MSset_oledb_prop;
   ```
4. `HDR=YES;IMEX=1`

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling SQL Server, SSMS and Microsoft Access database engine.

I tried installing everything in 32 bits since SSMS is only available in 32 bits, but SQL Server 2014 32 bits is not supported on 64 bits.

Comment: `Downloads\MyExcelFile.xlsx` that isn't a valid path.

Comment: `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` is not a supported scenario for SQL Server, as the driver is desgned to be used only a client app, not in a Windows service. While it sort of works, "usually", you won't get any help from MS. `AllowInProcess` willp robably make things worse not better. Yes, you probably need 64 bit, as SQL Server is 64 bit. SSMS has nothing to do with this, it's just the application you use for querying.